# Initializing a Hash with empty array unexpected behaviour

Tags: ruby, hash

I want to initialize a `Hash` with an empty `Array` and for every new key push a certain value to that array.

Here's what I tried to do:

```
a = Hash.new([])
# => {} 
a[1] << "asd"
# => ["asd"]
a
# => {}
```

The expected output for `a` was `{1 => ["asd"]}` but that didn't happen. What am I missing here?

Ruby version:

```
ruby 2.0.0p598 (2014-11-13 revision 48408) [x86_64-linux]
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just do

```
a = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = [] }
a[1] << "asd"
a # => {1=>["asd"]}
```

Read the below lines from the [`Hash::new`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Hash.html#method-c-new) documentation. It really explains why you didn't get the desired result.

*new(obj) → new_hash*

> If obj is specified, this single object will be used for all default values.

*new {|hash, key| block } → new_hash*

> If a block is specified, it will be called with the hash object and the key, and should return the default value. It is the block’s responsibility to store the value in the hash if required.

You can test by hand :

```
a = Hash.new([])
a[1].object_id # => 2160424560
a[2].object_id # => 2160424560
```

Now with the above style of `Hash` object creation, you can see every access to an *unknown key*, returning back the same **default** object. Now the other way, I meant *block way* :

```
b = Hash.new { |h, k| [] }
b[2].object_id # => 2168989980
b[1].object_id # => 2168933180
```

So, with the *block* form, every *unknown key* access, returning a new `Array` object.